# Node.js “UserLogged” function returning “undefined”. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I get to the end of the code below, it always returns "undefined" and I don't know why!

```
function UserLogged (session) {
  if (session === null) {
    var err = new Error('Not logged in');
    err.status = 400;
    return {user : null, err : err};
  }
  User.findById(session.userId)
  .exec(function (error, user) {
    if (error) {
      return {user : null, err : error};
    }
    else {
      if (user === null) {
        var err = new Error('Not authorized!');
        err.status = 400;
        return {user : null, err : err};
      }
      else {
        console.log("User found and ok!");
        return {user : user, err : null};
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It does log "User found and ok!" on the console, but still returns "undefined"

Comment: The UserLogged function only has one return statement in it, near the top. The return statements in the nested functions will not "return from" UserLogged. A function that does not have a return executed will always "return undefined". Might want to read up on 'Promises' and/or 'Callbacks' and/or 'Asynchronous Programming' (the 'async' keyword is *not* required), perhaps - as the data used to create the user object is only available asynchronously (and thus *cannot* be directly returned from UserLogged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserLogged is **Asynchronous** function so one way to handle is to add a callback:

```
function UserLogged (session, next) {
  if (session === null) {
    var err = new Error('Not logged in');
    err.status = 400;
    return next({user : null, err : err});
  }
  User.findById(session.userId)
  .exec(function (error, user) {
    if (error) {
      return next({user : null, err : error});
    }
    else {
      if (user === null) {
        var err = new Error('Not authorized!');
        err.status = 400;
        return next({user : null, err : err});
      }
      else {
        console.log("User found and ok!");
        return next({user : user, err : null});
      }
    }
  });
}
```

and then you call UserLogged like this:

```
something.UserLogged(sessionData, function(result) {
     console.log(result)
})
```